# How do I install System76 drivers on Kali and/or Parrot?

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, parrot-os

I just got a new System76 and I'm having freeze up issues on Kali or Parrot. I looked online and found that they are System76 drivers that have to be installed after a fresh Ubuntu install, but I can't get the commands to work on Kali or Parrot. I'm also new to Linux generally. My background is on the DOS/Windows side.

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](http://support.system76.com/articles/system76-driver/).

I created the preferences file.

[image]

but any time I try and add the repository I get an error.

Kali:

[image]

Parrot:

[image]

I tried to run these [drivers](https://github.com/pop-os/system76-driver) by running the make-release file as suggested on the readme but it bombs on the script, line 139.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kali is known to have trouble with various hardware. Also, Kali is meant for [penetration testing](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), not to install on your laptop. Kali is not "what all the hackers use", no matter what you read on some forums. Nobody uses Kali for daily work, except people new to Linux, who then promptly run into problems.

Your link points to drivers in Ubuntu repositories. So ditch Kali, install Ubuntu instead (which is a lot more user-friendly), install the drivers as explained by the link.

Then you can install all the hacking tools Kali has (if that is why you chose Kali), using Ubuntu's package manager.

Comment: What about ParrotOS? I'm not opposed to what you're saying, just your right in that, that's not the impression I got, seemed like everyone had Kali or Parrot installed as a dual boot.

Comment: I haven't used ParrotOS, so I cannot comment on that. And yes, I noticed lots of people doing stupid things since the Kali craze started - we get questions of "Kali is not working with my hardware" by people who try to install Kali as dual boot or in a VM with the regularity of a clockwork.